# ¿Cómo puedo solucionar el error "g++" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo trabajando en VSCode?

Tags: c++, vscode

Estoy intentando crear mi primer hola mundo en C pero tengo este error:

> "g++" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo

Adjunto imagen del error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es complicado programar en C en Visual Studio Code. Debes configurar bien el Workspace.

Comment: No tienes instalado `g++`.  Puedes instalarlo [aqui](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/).  La [guia que encuentras en la docu de vs code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp#_install-a-compiler) te puede ser de ayuda tambien.

Comment: Tu programa no es C sino C++. En C no tienes la librería `iostream` ni `cout`, de la misma manera que tampoco tienes espacios de nombres

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Necesitas instalar y configurar un compilador para vs code, si solamente vas a desarrollar proyectos simples mejor prueba con un compilador web como [onlinegdb](https://onlinegdb.com) para evitar complicaciones (y va a ser mucho más práctico), si piensas aprender a fondo C++ prueba visual studio, puedes codear, compilar y debuggear sin configuración previa.

Si realmente quieres codear en vs code, puedes utilizar [mingw](https://www.mingw-w64.org), pero tienes que configurar PATH (y no dudo que otras variables de entorno) para que funcione apoyándose de ese programa.

Te recomiendo mucho más onlinegdb y si te gusta C++, puedes instalar visual studio.